# Why the speed of my processor is reduced?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, speed, processor-socket

I have a motherboard model D865GLC, it is an old computer that needs an upgrade to use like a office worker or basic school, it has 4gb of ram, graphic tarjet agp8x of 64mb and pentium 4 2.20 ghz, I purchased a new processor to improve the previuos processor, a pentium 4 3.06 ghz.

When I set the new processor the speed is reduced and i don't know what is the reason.

In the BIOS configuration, the speed of the processor is 1.6 GHZ.

I checked the specs of my motherboard with the processor and are compatible

How can I make this run at full speed?

Attached a picture with more information, please say me if you need more information.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes motherboards need BIOS updates to support newer processors. Unfortunately Intel pulled all their downloads for older boards so it may not be easy to find.

Comment: Ok thanks, but now my computer has not a os, do you recomnded to install an os and after upgrade the BIOS